# Abnormal behavior X509Chain.Build() on Windows and Linux in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, tls1.2, client-certificates

Following is my certificate hierarchy: -
[image: Certificate Hierarchy]

I am having an embedded device which is connecting to my back end server on websocket protocol with TLS 1.2 security channel with client certificate authentication. My organization is having its own certificate authority for devices and back end server. Device is producing its certificate (without complete chain) in the format of `.pfx` to the back end server. Following is my code snippet

```
public static void ConfigureEndPoints(this KestrelServerOptions options)
{
    var configuration = options.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    foreach (var address in ipAddresses)
                {
                    switch ((EndPointType)config.Scheme)
                    {
                        case EndPointType.Plain:
                            options.Listen(address, port);
                            break;
                        case EndPointType.WithClientCert:
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.RootCertFile))
                                mRootCertFileName = config.RootCertFile;
                            if (config.IntermediateCerts != null)
                                mIntermediateCertFileNames = config.IntermediateCerts;
                            options.Listen(address, port, listenOptions =>
                            {
                                listenOptions.UseHttps(config.FileName, config.Password, configureOptions =>
                                {
                                    configureOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                                    configureOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11;

                                    
                                    configureOptions.ClientCertificateValidation += VerifyClientCertificate;
                                  
                                });
                            });
                            break;
                        case EndPointType.WithoutClientCert:
                            options.Listen(address, port, listenOptions =>
                            {
                                listenOptions.UseHttps(config.FileName, config.Password, configureOptions =>
                                {
                                    configureOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate;
                                    configureOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11;
                                });
                            });
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine($"Invalid scheme value {config.Scheme}");
                            break;
                    }
                }

     private static bool VerifyClientCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicy)
        {
            List<X509Certificate2> intermediateCerts = null;
            try
            {
                X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);

                if (mIntermediateCertFileNames != null)
                {
                    foreach (string certFileName in mIntermediateCertFileNames)
                    {
                        if (intermediateCerts == null)
                            intermediateCerts = new List<X509Certificate2>();
                        X509Certificate2 clientIntermediateCert = new X509Certificate2(certFileName);
                        intermediateCerts.Add(clientIntermediateCert);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                List<X509Certificate2> additionalCerts = intermediateCerts.ToList();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mRootCertFileName))
                    additionalCerts.Add(new X509Certificate2(mRootCertFileName));
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                bool status = VerifyCertificate(clientCert, additionalCerts);
                if (status)
                {
                    if (!(clientCert.NotAfter.ToUniversalTime() >= DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() &&
                          clientCert.NotBefore.ToUniversalTime() <= DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()))
                    {
                        status = false;
                    }
                }
                return status;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


     static bool VerifyCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCert, List<X509Certificate2> additionalCerts)
        {
            
            bool status = true;
            bool thumbPrintMatch;
            var chain = new X509Chain();
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreWrongUsage;
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
            foreach (var cert in additionalCerts)
            {
                chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(cert);
            }

            try
            {
                status = chain.Build(clientCert);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            

           
            
            if (status)
            {  
                if (chain.ChainElements.Count != chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Count + 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                for(var i = 1; i < chain.ChainElements.Count; i++)
                {
                    thumbPrintMatch = false;
                    for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        
                        if(chain.ChainElements[i].Certificate.Thumbprint == chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore[j].Thumbprint)
                        {
                            thumbPrintMatch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!thumbPrintMatch)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                return false;

            return status;
        }
```

The above code is working absolutely fine on Windows 10 when I added all the required Root and Intermediate certificates in the Windows store. `status = chain.Build(clientCert);` is giving `status as true` and also give `chain.ChainElements.Count` as 4 which is correct i.e. it is building complete chain of the device certificate from leaf certificate to root CA (total 4).All this is working fine on windows without adding `chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;` flag.

Now on Linux (CentOS7), I have added TestRootCA.crt, DeviceIntermediate1.crt and DeviceIntermediate2.crt in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` folder and ran `update-ca-trust extract` command. Following are observations after that: -

1. `status = chain.Build(clientCert);` will not return `true` until I add `chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;` flag. I don't want to add this flag to implement strict security constraint.
2. If I added `chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;` flag then also `chain.ChainElements.Count` is giving only 1 i.e. the leaf certificate of the device. It is not able to build complete chain.

I have done one more thing that if I made my device to produce its certificate with complete chain in `.p12` format then my server is able to authenticate it properly. But I am not sure whether it is correct to modify device to provide certificate with complete chain or not? Whether there is some security threat in it?

Where .NET CORE is searching for all certificates for trust??
How to modify my code so that I can implement strict security constraint for linux environment also, with `.pfx` without sending device chain.

Hope I am able to explain all the things. Any idea related to this will be a great help.

Comment: It looks in the `certs` directory and `cert.pem` file in whatever directory `openssl version -d` reports.  The place to start debugging is the first missing cert, e.g. Device Intermediate 2.

Comment: It is available in /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem file. All the three CAs TestRootCA, DeviceIntermediate1CA and DeviceIntermediate2CA are available in cert.pem file.

Comment: Hm.  if `openssl verify -show_chain clientcert.pem` succeeds and looks right then X509Chain should work.  If that doesn't work, then OpenSSL doesn't like some characteristic about your CA/chain, and X509Chain won't work.  (If it's "should work, but doesn't" then open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues, but unless we can reproduce the error locally we won't be able to do anything about it.)

Comment: I am getting error as ```error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate```. when I ran ```openssl verify -show_chain clientcert.pem```. Any idea on this.

Comment: Well, that's why .NET doesn't like the chain, then :).  Working on Windows and not with OpenSSL is rare, but happens.  I don't think there's a good way to help without seeing examples of the client cert (public portion) and the issuer cert.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the problem by modifying my device (gateway) to send its certificate along with its complete chain to server during client authentication.
There are couple of things that I came to know from this: -

1. Device must send its certificate with complete chain to server.
2. Need not to install Intermediate certificates of device chain on the server, these must be send by the device in its certificate.
3. Windows automatically build the complete chain, even if the device is not sending its complete chain but device Intermediate certificates are installed in Windows Cert Store. That's why this problem is not observed on windows.
4. Linux is not behaving in this way. It will not build the complete chain if device is not sending its certificate with complete chain, even if the intermediate device certificates are installed in Linux Cert store.